# Visual Studio Code Intellisense stopped working

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I can not recall when it exactly happened but all of a sudden the Intellisense stopped working completly. I was programming `Javascript` and `ReactNative`

There is no autocomplete anymore and when I hover over a method there is only `Loading...` displayed.

I tried to reload the window, also with all extensions disabled but nothing changed. I have no idea how to get it back...

[EDIT]
Intellisense works on other folders/projects but not on this specific one.

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of visual studio code you are currently using?

Comment: version 1.38.1 on windows 10

Comment: This version has intenseness issue faced by many people.Please try downgrading the version to previous one.It will be fine then.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now.

Comment: And its not working again, tried 3 different versions.

Comment: I have the exact same problem :(